# We may would accept your story - Using may would together

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

"We may would accept your story."

The sentence want to speak in future, they "probably" (at the place of probably have used "may") would accept it.

Here "may" and "would" have used together.

Is it grammatical to use them both together at this sentence?

Comment: No, that sentence doesn't make sense.  But to give a proper answer can you provide more context?  The sentence before and after should be enough.

Comment: There's some dialectal double modal usage, but it's definitely not standard.

Answer (score 2):

Auxilliary verbs

- can
- could
- may
- might
- shall
- should
- will
- would
- do *(sometimes)*

You can only use one modal *auxilliary* ("helper") verb in each verbal group.

With *do*, if it's the first verb, it's an auxiliary, and it can only be the first and/or last verb in the verbal group.

**Well-formed**

- I *did* eat the food. *(emphasis on having eaten the food, instead of not eating it)*
- I *did do* my homework. *(emphasis on having done the homework, instead of not doing it)*
- I would *do* my homework, but...

**Not well-formed**

- I do should my homework.
- I had done shot the cat (although I have a feeling that this, without the *that*, is heard in some parts of the United States - please correct me if I'm misinformed)

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. In this sentence "We may would accept your story." How can I re-construct the sentence? Using "may" as "probably" and "would" to say it in future.

Comment: You can use lots of auxiliaries.  "The photo will have been being taken."  But you can only use one *modal* auxiliary.  You need to distinguish the four auxiliary slots.